# Java regex matcher groups doesnt match

Tags: java, regex

I want to match different formats of list in a text file. basically I would like to be able to match

> One,Two,Three,Four

or

> "One"; "Two"; "Three"; "Four"

And I would like to extract the separator and the quote. ("" and "," for the first example and "\"" and ";" for the second)

I did this:

```
String regexp = "(?<delim>[^\\w\\n\"']?)(?<space> ?)(?<quote>[\"']?).*?\\k<quote>\\k<delim>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  while (matcher.find()) {
    String delim = matcher.group("delim");
    String quote = matcher.group("quote");
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

I only get a single group containing the complete string tested when I do `matcher.group()`. `matcher.group("delim")` and quote are always empty. I realize that it is a problem with my delim group being optional however I also tried the following regex wich although matches on online regex tester never match anyting in my code:

```
String regexp = "(?<delim>[^\\w\\n\"'])(?<space> ?)(?<quote>[\"']?).*?\\k<quote>\\k<delim>";
```

What I am doing wrong in my regex ?

Comment: Remove the `if (matcher.matches())`, use just the `while (matcher.find())`.

Comment: If I remove the `matcher.matches()` before the `matcher.find()` the `matcher.find()` returns `true` but `matcher.group()` is null

Comment: @banetl If `matcher.find()` returns `true`, then it means *some* match was found, so since `group()` is shorthand for `group(0)` it can't return `null` but that *some* match (even if it will be empty string like `""` for regex such as `a*`). Did you perhaps mean some other group than `group(0)` like `group("delim")`? If yes then please be specific about it, otherwise we can assume things which are not true for problem you are describing.

Comment: When I remove the `matcher.matches()` `matcher.group()` returns an empty String and `matcher.group("delim")` throws the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No group with name <delim>`. However when I let it `matcher.group()` returns the whole String, with my first example it would be `"One,Two,Three,Four"`

Comment: The only solution for this I can think of [involves a conditional construct](https://regex101.com/r/Fjhkhq/1) that is not supported by Java regex. You will have to rewrite the regex in a more verbose way, and add specific logic in the code. See [**this demo**](http://ideone.com/fRVOrO) and [**another demo here**](http://ideone.com/HnOPs3).

Comment: Why don't you just use `String[] data = line.split("\\W+");`? or `regexp = "\\w+";` and ignore the delimiters.

Comment: The purpose of this regex is to find the delimiters and quote. @WiktorStribiżew solution with a conditional construct works perfectly.

Comment: But the other one for Java does not seem good :(

Comment: Three Qs: do you want to capture the contents ("one", "two", etc) or just the quote and separator?  If the separator or quote changes, e.g. 'one', "two"; 'three', "four" -- is that a match?  And what about a singleton: 'one' -- is that a match?

Comment: @fearless_fool I only want to capture the quote and separator. If the separator and quote match I still wish to match it. If the input string is a singleton "one", I would like it to match quote to " and delimiter to empty string

Comment: @banetl - sorry to pester you with more questions, but what would be captured for the quote and the separator for 'one', "two"; 'three', "four"?

Comment: This case is an error, the regex shouldn't match anything